# How to retrieve the result value and a select statement of a stored procedure at the same time in C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

OK so this might sound a bit weird!
The thing is that in a project there are many stored procedure already written like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [Status_Insert]

        @StatusId       int OUTPUT,
        @Status         nvarchar (50),
        @IsDeleted      bit = 0

AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;

BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRAN

INSERT INTO dbo.[Status]
(
        [Status],
        [IsDeleted]
)
VALUES
(
        @Status,
        @IsDeleted
)

SET @StatusId = @@IDENTITY

COMMIT TRAN
RETURN 1
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
ROLLBACK TRAN

DECLARE @ErrorNumber_INT INT;
DECLARE @ErrorSeverity_INT INT;
DECLARE @ErrorProcedure_VC VARCHAR(200);
DECLARE @ErrorLine_INT INT;
DECLARE @ErrorMessage_NVC NVARCHAR(4000);

SELECT
        @ErrorMessage_NVC = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
        @ErrorSeverity_INT = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
        @ErrorNumber_INT = ERROR_NUMBER(),
        @ErrorProcedure_VC = ERROR_PROCEDURE(),
        @ErrorLine_INT = ERROR_LINE()

RETURN -1
END CATCH
```

The primary key is an `Identity` and an output variable is used to retrieve its value after the insert statement. (By the way, is this approach a good practice?)
Now the return values are used to indicate the success or failure of the procedure. (IE.  if the operation was successful 1 is returned and -1 is returned if the operation has failed)
If there is an error in the execution of the procedure, the last select statement will return the error to the user.

Now how can I call this procedure in C# and get these results at the same time?
What I want to do is, execute the procedure, and get the return value, if it was 1 then get the result of the last select statement (which contains more info about the error that has occured)
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use "ReturnValue" parameter in Command.

```
using(var connection = GetOpenConnection()) {
    using(var cmd = connection.CreateCommand()){
        cmd.CommandText = "Status_Insert";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        var prmReturnValue = new SqlParameter( "@ReturnValue", DBNull.Value );
        prmReturnValue.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

        using(var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
            // process table result(s)
        }

        var returnValue = prmReturnValue.Value;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
The problem is in select. If you select something into variable, the select will not be in result-sets.

If you want assign variable(s) from functions you don't need SELECT statement, you can use SET command or you can initialize values in DECLARE statement (from version 2008):

```
/* variable initialization in DECLARE statements >>> */
DECLARE @ErrorNumber_INT INT              = ERROR_NUMBER();
DECLARE @ErrorSeverity_INT INT            = ERROR_SEVERITY();
DECLARE @ErrorProcedure_VC VARCHAR(200)   = ERROR_PROCEDURE();
/* <<< variable initialization in DECLARE statements */

/* variable initialization with SET statements >>> */
DECLARE @ErrorLine_INT INT;
DECLARE @ErrorMessage_NVC NVARCHAR(4000);
SET @ErrorLine_INT INT = ERROR_LINE();
SET @ErrorMessage_NVC  = ERROR_MESSAGE();
/* <<< variable initialization with SET statements */

/* this select will be in result-set(s) >>> */
SELECT
        @ErrorNumber_INT AS [ErrorNumber_INT],
        @ErrorSeverity_INT AS [ErrorSeverity_INT],
        @ErrorProcedure_VC AS [ErrorProcedure_VC],
        @ErrorLine_INT AS [ErrorLine_INT],
        @ErrorMessage_NVC AS [ErrorMessage_NVC]
/* <<< this select will be in result-set(s) */
```

Comment: So I just have to declare an extra variable of type int in C# with the Direction set to ReturnValue? After the procedure finished, the result is return in that and the error info could be retrieved with ExecuteReader?

Comment: BTW is defining the PrimaryKey (Identity) as OUTPUT type a good practice as well?

Comment: The OUTPUT parameters are absolutelly OK. The good practise is definining default values for OUTPUT parameters for better manual calling of procedure: CREATE PROC MyProce @StatusID int OUTPUT = NULL AS .... Then you can run the procedure without handling OUTPUT parameter.

Comment: @TcKs: I've notice something. The "select" for error checkings is never returned form the procedure as it only assigns the local variables declared before it! like @ErrorNumber_INT! Is there a way I could fix this problem and still have -1 returned from the procedure in case of error??